# Github Credentials Difference on Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, git, ubuntu, bitbucket

I'm using HTTPS clone method in Bitbucket. But I still wonder why in Windows I dont need to use credentials helper and even only need to login once (and that's through a GUI) everytime I push, pull and etc. But in Ubuntu I have to use credential helper otherwise I have to type my username and password in every command I did and it's through terminal. Can anyone explain this to me? And is there anything I can do in Ubuntu so I dont have to use credential helper which has timeout? Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no another way dude :(

**You Can Try This**

**Ubuntu Command for caching Your Credentials**

> Change Your Timeout Whatever You want.

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
$ git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: hey thanks for reply my comment dude :)
can you explain to me why this happen only in Linux? I know that HTTPS need credentials everytime, but how can this not affect Windows? I just wonder when this thing happens..

Comment: I don't have proper answer but in windows git bash has its own credential caching functionality so this issue not happening in windows

Comment: ah I see, git bash. I dont have it on Ubuntu.. thanks for your explanation dude

Comment: wc :) keep coding :)